Rasp Pi Camera or Camera + Lens Combo that has Minimum Focus Distance <= 5 cm
Does anyone knew of a raspberry pi camera that had a minimum focus distance of 5 cm or less? I'm taking photos of an object at least that close. I don't know if this is the correct place to ask this question, but I'm not sure where to find this information.

this might help ... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120254/how-close-can-the-new-high-quality-camera-focus-with-the-16-mm-c-mount-lens-as
